# JavaScript Windows 8 How to have a different background per page in Navigation?

Tags: javascript, css, windows-8, navigation

I want to have a different background for each page that I make. I need it to be able to refresh the background image on each page. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Just throw this in your head:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background: url(imagegoeshere.jpg);
    }
</style>
```

And change it on each page you want.

Comment: I just implemented that, but when I try to go back, the image stays the same. It does not go back to the image for that page.

Comment: Add it after you call your normal CSS files, and just be sure to edit the area you want. It may or may not be the body.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the body on each individual page.

```
 <body class=pageName>
 ...
 </body>

 .pageName {
      background: url(example.gif);
 }
```